# Problems after Qooxdoo migration to 1.3-pre

Tags: migration, qooxdoo

I checked out the latest SVN trunk of qooxdoo and now i have the following problems:

- Some events seems that they are not comming through
- Virtual Lists are not filled anymore (the _createWidget() method of the extension from qx.ui.virtual.cell.AbstractWidget is not called)

My original version was QX 1.0.1-pre and the problems appeared also when i tried to migrate to 1.2

Comment: i found out that a vitual list has to be bound by initialisation and may not be modified (neither the bound array, nor the Controller). This was the solution for the VirtualLists problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the event seems to be a [bug in Qooxdoo](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4250)

Answer (score 1):

Just to get the obvious stuff out of the way, did you follow the steps of the [migration guide](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.2/pages/migration/migration_guide.html) and make any necessary changes outlined in migration.log?

Aside from that, the virtual widgets are still experimental and no migration path is provided, meaning you'll have to go over your code and check if the parts of the ui.virtual API you're using have changed since 1.0.1.

For the missing events, please provide some more information: What events are you listening for?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your awnser. I followed the migration guide without success. It seems that i have to avoid using the virtual widgets until a stable version is out. The 'evnts' are only HTML links in a table with HTML-Renderer. The links do not work anymore. How can i debug this event chain? Thanks.